# How to make SQLAlchemy hybrid_property select expressions work for both select and filter

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been attempting to write some expressions with hybrid properties, but I've found them to be extremely limited and I'm wondering if I can get around those limits.

Basically, I've found they either work with `session.query(Model.hybrid_property)` or `session.query(Model).filter(Model.hybrid_property==x)`, but not both.

Here's an example of what I mean, assume there are two rows called `value1` and `value2`, and `name` is a `hybrid_property`.

```
# With as_scalar()
>>> session.query(Model).filter(Model.value=='value1').all()
[([<__main__.Model object],)]         # this is wanted
>>> session.query(Model.value).all()
[(u'value1',)]

# Without as scalar()
>>> session.query(Model).filter(Model.value=='value1').all()
[]
>>> session.query(Model.value).all()
[(u'value1',), (u'value2',)]          # this is wanted
```

Depending on if `as_scalar()` is used, it changes what it works with. Is there a way to make it work with both?

Here's some example code (edited to show an example that fully doesn't work):

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, select, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship

Engine = create_engine('sqlite://')

Base = declarative_base(bind=Engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=Base.metadata.bind)


class ModelRelation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ModelRelation'
    row_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64))


class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Model'
    row_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    relation_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('ModelRelation.row_id'))

    relation = relationship('ModelRelation')

    @hybrid_property
    def value(self):
        return self.relation.name

    @value.expression
    def value(cls):
        return select([ModelRelation.name]).where(ModelRelation.row_id==cls.relation_id)

    @hybrid_property
    def value_scalar(self):
        return self.relation.name

    @value_scalar.expression
    def value_scalar(cls):
        return select([ModelRelation.name]).where(ModelRelation.row_id==cls.relation_id).as_scalar()


Base.metadata.create_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = Session()

    script1 = Model(relation=ModelRelation(name='value1'))
    session.add(script1)
    script2 = Model(relation=ModelRelation(name='value2'))
    session.add(script2)
    session.commit()

    print([i.value for i in session.query(Model).all()])
    print(session.query(Model.value).all())
    print(session.query(Model).filter(Model.value=='value1').all())
    print()
    print([i.value_scalar for i in session.query(Model).all()])
    print(session.query(Model.value_scalar).all())
    print(session.query(Model).filter(Model.value_scalar=='value1').all())

    session.close()
```

The output of that is:

```
[u'value1', u'value2']
[(u'value1',), (u'value2',)]
[]

[u'value1', u'value2']
[(u'value1',)]
[<__main__.Model object at 0x041D5C90>]
```

Comment: I don't think you are meant to have more than one expression per `@hybrid_property` and you don't call the expression method directly, still query on the `@hybrid_property` attribute. E.g. delete `value_scalar()` method, this `session.query(Model.value).all()` returns `[('value1',), ('value2',)]`, and `session.query(Model).filter(Model.value == "value1").all()` returns `[<__main__.Model object at 0x0000022578989E08>]`. Didn't write an answer as not sure I've understood your question properly, but I've not seen the pattern where a single hybrid property has multiple expression methods before.

Comment: This is the sql generated by the `.filter(Model.value_not_scalar == "value1")` query: `SELECT "Model".row_id AS "Model_row_id", "Model".name AS "Model_name"
FROM "Model"
WHERE 0 = 1`. Note the `WHERE 0 = 1` part at the end, hence the empty result.

Comment: I'm not normally doing two expressions on one property, I just found it gave the same result. When I cleaned up my code, it hadn't dawned on me that removing relationships would allow `hybrid_property` to generate the expressions automatically, but my actual issue is over relationships where this doesn't happen. With a relationship added again though (I'll update the code in the question), it doesn't work without specifically defining the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variability you are seeing is due to the type of object that the expression is returning and where the expression is being used.

**With No `as_scalar()`:**

Your expression returns a `Select` object.

In `session.query(Model.value).all()`, your expression is being passed to `session.query()` which from [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=session%20query#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.__init__) can accept:

> a sequence of entities and/or SQL expressions.

... so that's fine. We can prove that with this simple query:

```py
print(session.query(select([1])).all())  # [(1,)]
```

In the second query, `session.query(Model).filter(Model.value == "value1").all()`, you are now using the Select on the left hand side of an equality comparison, and the result of that comparison is then passed to `query.filter()`. SQLAlchemy uses rich comparison for comparing column(like) elements by overloading the `__eq__()` method on `Column`, you can see this for your self:

```py
print(Column.__eq__)  # <function ColumnOperators.__eq__ at 0x000001F851FB11F8>
```

But your expression returns a `Select` object:

```py
print(Select.__eq__)  # <slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'object' objects>
# which is just the same __eq__ method that every python object has, defined on object
print(Select.__eq__ is object.__eq__)  # True
```

Now that we know that `Select.__eq__()` method hasn't been overloaded, what will be the result of any `==` comparison between a `Select` object and a string? Always `False`. What happens when we pass `False` as the only filter to a query?:

```py
print(session.query(Model).filter(False).all())
# SELECT "Model".row_id AS "Model_row_id", "Model".relation_id AS "Model_relation_id" FROM "Model" WHERE 0 = 1
```

`WHERE 0 = 1` always evaluates false, so the query is always empty.

**With `as_scalar()`:**

From [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.as_scalar) for `Select.as_scalar()`:

> return a ‘scalar’ representation of this selectable, which can be used
>   as a column expression.
>
> Typically, a select statement which has only one column in its columns
>   clause is eligible to be used as a scalar expression.
>
> The returned object is an instance of ScalarSelect.

So in this scanario, the expression returns a `ScalarSelect` object which can be treated like a column.

First, addressing the difference between the behavior of the `.filter(Model.value_scalar=='value1')` query:

```py
print(ScalarSelect.__eq__ is Column.__eq__)  # True
```

ScalarSelect has the same `__eq__()` implementation as `Column` which means that in the context of `Query.filter()` equality testing produces something meaningful:

```py
print(Model.value_scalar == "value1")
# (SELECT "ModelRelation".name FROM "ModelRelation", "Model" WHERE "ModelRelation".row_id = "Model".relation_id) = :param_1
```

So in this context the query produces sensible results.

However, in the `session.query(Model.value_scalar).all()` case, it only returns a single value, even though there are two rows in the table.

The sql that this query generates is this:

```
SELECT (SELECT "ModelRelation".name
FROM "ModelRelation", "Model"
WHERE "ModelRelation".row_id = "Model".relation_id) AS anon_1
```

As the `ScalarSelect` is being interpreted as a column, it itself is being selected, rather than being selected from, as it is in the no `as_scalar()` case. It's a bit beyond me as to why `SELECT (SELECT...) AS anon_1` only returns a single row from the query, but I can show you that it happens at the database level, it's not sqlalchemy handling the results and only returning one for some reason. This executes the same query through the raw dbapi connection:

```py
with Engine.connect() as conn:
    cxn = conn.connection
    cursor = cxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT (SELECT "ModelRelation".name
        FROM "ModelRelation", "Model"
        WHERE "ModelRelation".row_id = "Model".relation_id) AS anon_1
    """)
    print(cursor.fetchall())  # [('value1',)]
```

So it seems you'll get the most consistent behavior when the expression returns a `Column`.

There is a section in the documentation about [Join Dependent Hybrid Relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#join-dependent-relationship-hybrid) where it just uses the related object column as the expression value, but you need to supply the join in the query.

If the model is:

```py
class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Model"
    row_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    relation_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("ModelRelation.row_id"))

    relation = relationship("ModelRelation")

    @hybrid_property
    def value(self):
        return self.relation.name

    @value.expression
    def value(cls):
        return ModelRelation.name
```

This query: `session.query(Model.value).all()` renders as

```
SELECT "ModelRelation".name AS "ModelRelation_name" FROM "ModelRelation"
```

...and returns `[('value1',), ('value2',)]` as expected.

However this query: `session.query(Model).filter(Model.value == "value1").all()` renders as:

```
SELECT "Model".row_id AS "Model_row_id", "Model".relation_id AS "Model_relation_id" 
FROM "Model", "ModelRelation" 
WHERE "ModelRelation".name = ?
```

...but returns both rows even though we've filtered on the value: `[<__main__.Model object at 0x000002060369FEC8>, <__main__.Model object at 0x000002060348B108>]`.

In this part of the docs they are dealing with models called `User` and `SavingsAccount` and they say:

> However, at the expression level, it’s expected that the User class
>   will be used in an appropriate context such that an appropriate join
>   to SavingsAccount will be present

So if we make the query `session.query(Model).join(ModelRelation).filter(Model.value == "value1").all()`, the rendered query becomes:

```
SELECT "Model".row_id AS "Model_row_id", "Model".relation_id AS "Model_relation_id" 
FROM "Model" JOIN "ModelRelation" 
ON "ModelRelation".row_id = "Model".relation_id 
WHERE "ModelRelation".name = ?
```

...and returns the correct 1 result: `[<__main__.Model object at 0x000001606F030D48>]`.

The docs go on to describe another example, [Correlated Subquery Relationship Hybrid](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#correlated-subquery-relationship-hybrid), but I find that has the exact same limitation as above when the `select()` is the target entity of the query in that it only returns a single result.

Comment: Ah thanks a bunch for the very detailed reply, it's useful to know why it's working the way it is. I'm glad you found the way around this particular issue, though the limitations of the expressions in general are definitely a bit of a shame.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way that the ScalarSelect et. al might be specifically handled as a target of a query but I read an interesting quote today, something like, ‘the limitations in software that frustrate us are most likely due to constraints  that we don’t understand’. I would have a small bet that that is the case here too.

Comment: Haha that can be true. I guess it's just that `SQLAlchemy` is normally very intuitive and easy to use, but suddenly you have cases like this, where the solutions with finer control don't work quite as expected, and the working solution (in this case, returning `ModelRelation.name`) feels a little limited if you were needing to do something more complex :)

Comment: As always with open source, the future is in your hands. There is a mailing list where you might find a better explanation of the reasons why this stuff behaves like it does, and if indeed it can be done better, that would be a good place to instigate a change. https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/sqlalchemy